# Does sending images on Google Hangouts count towards my Google account storage space?

Tags: google-hangouts

Does sending images on Google Hangouts (Android application) count towards my Google account storage space?

I don't see why it would, but right after sending some images via Google Hangouts I received an email regarding my Google account storage, so I wonder whether this is a coincidence:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: When I interpret the [Hangout help (see the "Delete photos and videos" section)](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115410?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1) it seems like sent images are saved in the "Photos from Hangouts" album on your device. And if this album is automatically synced via Google Photos it may have an effect on the GDrive storage. You should check this album on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the images which are sent via google hangouts are stored in your account storage. Refer [this link](https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard) to see all of your account storage on Google Dashboard. Click on Gmail to see stats. Click on chats to see all of your images.

Take this image as a reference.

[image: image here]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Yes, they are stored in you account, but your account storage is not negatively affected at all by photos stored in your account if they are "high quality" as opposed to "original quality".

Comment: Come June 2021 and the answer is actually correct. All pictures now count towards the drive size.

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ Do you know any way to check how much storage is used by images uploaded to Hangouts?